# Computing expected values with regard to beta distributions

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, expected-value

Can someone help me compute the following  expected value?

Considering $q_1(\theta_1) = Beta(\alpha_1,\beta_1)$,$q_2(\theta_2) = Beta(\alpha_2,\beta_2)$ and $q_3(\theta_3) = Beta(\alpha_3,\beta_3)$.

Note that $\theta_1$ , $\theta_2$,$\theta_3$ are independent.

I need to compute the following expected value:
$$
 E_{q_2(\theta_2),q_3(\theta_3)} [
        \log(\theta_1)(4\alpha_1-2)+\log(1-\theta_1)(4\beta_3-2)+
        \log(\theta_2)4\alpha_2+\log(1-\theta_2)4\beta_2+
        \log(\theta_3)[4\alpha_3-2]+\log(1-\theta_3)(4\beta_3-2)
]
$$

After computing this expected value, the goal is to elevate it to exponential and try to make the result look like a new beta distribution.

I am not really familiar with this type of expected value, and I don't know how to approach it. Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 0):

This one can be brute-forced by Mathematica integrator ; however, expressing the algorithm is way easier to write in Sage (currently 9.8.beta4) :

```
# Variables and assumptions
Alpha=[var("alpha%s"%u, domain="positive") for u in (1..3)]
Beta=[var("beta%s"%u, domain="positive") for u in (1..3)]
Theta=[var("theta%s"%u) for u in (1..3)]
for u in Theta: assume(u>=0, u<=1)
var("a, b", domain="positive")
# Beta PDF
dbeta(x, a, b)=x^(a-1)*(1-x)^(b-1)/beta(a, b)
# Expression to integrate
Ex=log(theta1)*(4*alpha1-2)+log(1-theta1)*(4*beta3-2) + \
   log(theta2)*4*alpha2 + log(1-theta2)*4*beta2 + \
   log(theta3)*(4*alpha3-2)+log(1-theta3)*(4*beta3-2)
# Integration via Mathematica (other Sage integrators currently fail).
foo = mathematica.Integrate(*( # Probability * Expression
    [mathematica.FullSimplify((prod([dbeta(Theta[u],Alpha[u],Beta[u])
                                     for u in range(3)])*Ex)).sage()] +\
    [[u, 0, 1] for u in Theta])) # Integration variables and bounds
# Have a look
ConditionalExpression[(2*(alpha1 + beta1)*Gamma[alpha1]*Gamma[alpha2]*
   Gamma[alpha3]*Gamma[beta1]*Gamma[beta2]*Gamma[beta3]*
   ((-1 + 2*alpha1)*(alpha3 + beta3)*PolyGamma[0, alpha1] + 
    2*alpha2*(alpha3 + beta3)*PolyGamma[0, alpha2] + 
    (-1 + 2*alpha3)*(alpha3 + beta3)*PolyGamma[0, alpha3] + 
    (alpha3 + beta3)*(-1 + 2*beta3)*PolyGamma[0, beta1] - 
    2*(-1 + alpha1 + beta3)*(alpha3 + beta3)*PolyGamma[0, alpha1 + beta1] + 
    2*beta2*(alpha3 + beta3)*PolyGamma[0, beta2] - 
    2*(alpha2 + beta2)*(alpha3 + beta3)*PolyGamma[0, alpha2 + beta2] + 
    (alpha3 + beta3)*(-1 + 2*beta3)*PolyGamma[0, beta3] - 
    2*((-1 + beta3)*beta3 + alpha3*(-1 + alpha3 + 2*beta3))*
     PolyGamma[0, alpha3 + beta3]))/(Beta[alpha1, beta1]*Beta[alpha2, beta2]*
   Beta[alpha3, beta3]*Gamma[1 + alpha1 + beta1]*Gamma[alpha2 + beta2]*
   Gamma[1 + alpha3 + beta3]), Re[alpha1] > 0 && Re[beta1] > 0 && 
  Re[alpha3] > 0 && Re[beta3] > 0 && Re[alpha2] > 0 && Re[beta2] > 0]
```

The condition amounts to have $\forall i,\ \Re(\alpha_i)>0,\,\Re(\beta_i)>0$. The result amounts to :

```
# Simplify and restitute un Sage
mathematica.FullSimplify(foo[1]).sage(locals={"PolyGamma":psi})
```

i. e.

$$ -4 \, {\left(\alpha_{1} + \beta_{3} - 1\right)} \psi\left(\alpha_{1} + \beta_{1}\right) + 2 \, {\left(2 \, \alpha_{1} - 1\right)} \psi\left(\alpha_{1}\right) - 4 \, {\left(\alpha_{2} + \beta_{2}\right)} \psi\left(\alpha_{2} + \beta_{2}\right) + 4 \, \alpha_{2} \psi\left(\alpha_{2}\right) - 4 \, {\left(\alpha_{3} + \beta_{3} - 1\right)} \psi\left(\alpha_{3} + \beta_{3}\right) + 2 \, {\left(2 \, \alpha_{3} - 1\right)} \psi\left(\alpha_{3}\right) + 2 \, {\left(2 \, \beta_{3} - 1\right)} \psi\left(\beta_{1}\right) + 4 \, \beta_{2} \psi\left(\beta_{2}\right) + 2 \, {\left(2 \, \beta_{3} - 1\right)} \psi\left(\beta_{3}\right) $$

HTH,

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: taking the exponential of that result won't lead to a beta distribution? or maybe an unnormalized beta distribution?

Comment: Dear Community @bot : what enlightment do you expect ?

Dear Sam : why would you expect this expectation to be the log of something (what) having a Beta distribution ?